# How to check what user deleted a folder on Windows Server 2003 and restore it

Tags: windows-server-2003

Is there a way in Windows server 2003 to check what user deleted a directory?

A coworker has deleted a folder. I don't know who so I must check who deleted it and restore it.

Is there a way to restore data in Windows Server 2003?

Comment: Obligatory 2k3 is unsupported: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2003/

Comment: Are you trying to undelete the directory and it's contents or recover it from a backup ?

Comment: @lain: I'm trying to undelete a directory and it's contents.

Comment: I don't windows but searching for ntfs undelete or windows undelete in your favorite search engine will probably get you to where you need to be to start

Comment: Unless you had auditing enabled and configured for files and folders prior to the deletion then there isn't any way that I'm aware of to determine who deleted the folder. Secondarily (but more importantly) if you don't have backups of your important data then that's something that you ought to put at the top of your priority list.